# Need suggestions for dynamically creating views in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I am going to start one app where my activity page will contain "n" grouped views. Grouped view means "collections of views (i.e. One group can have TextView+Button+ImageView)". So the page will have "n" number of such grouped views.

I need suggestions like what would be the best practice to implement this. I could think of below ones:

1) Should a ScrollView  be used (Then I will have to create groups in runtime and place one under another)?

2) Or a ListView be used (Then how can I accommodate the height of each row as grouped views height may differ from each other?)

Or is there any other way I can go along with?

Appreciate the suggestions and any sample examples if have. Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options would work, it really depends on your use case.

- Place a vertical LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView and add your grouped-views to the LinearLayout. I would recommend this if you have a relatively small number of such views (not necessarily a fixed number, but small enough that you wouldn't have to scroll many "pages" to see them all). Make sure the ScrollView has `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and the LinearLayout has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.
- If the number of grouped-views is not small, you could use a ListView and make an Adapter for it. This lets you take advantage of ListView's automatic view recycling when items get scrolled off screen.

For either case, make an XML file for just the grouped-views. In code, you would get a LayoutInflater object (usually by calling `Activity.getLayoutInflater()`) and call `inflate(R.layout.your_grouped_views, null)`. If using the LinearLayout, you would add it in code with one of the `LinearLayout.addView(..)` methods; if using the ListView, your adapter would return the whole thing from `getView(...)`.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I feel this seems to be more approachable.

Answer (score 1):

1. create one xml layout containing the constant elements of your group view.
2. in you main xml layout which will be the `contentView` of your application, put a **ScrollView** and a single **LinearLayout**.
3. then in the program `inflate` as many views of your group view as you want.

Answer (score -1):

For your answer i want to give you referance of this [website](http://sampleprogramz.com/), on this website you can learn create dynamic view in android...

Comment: Here is not place where you can make your website commercial. If you really believe that the link will help, so give the exact thread link, not website link, please.

Comment: @Savan, this is nice link. But whatever you are trying to provide me a solution, where is that? I couldn't find any help regarding that.